# Viewing contents on the stack

Tags: c, assembly, stack

I am experimenting with assembly. Right now I am looking at some simple c code and how its translated into assembly using:

```
gcc -Wall -S -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -o test.s test.c -m32
```

I am just wondering if there is some tool that lets you view the contents that is on the stack? I can look at the assembly code for all the push instructions, but some assembly instructions (like call) push stuff on the stack aswell.

Are there any tools that can better visualize what exactly happens with the stack when running assembly or c code?

Comment: Your debugger will give you this visibility, and will let you single step through individual assembly instructions as they execute.

Comment: You're looking for a **debugger**, such as `gdb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, what you want is the well known debugger gdb. You can run the program like so

gdb ./{program}

Then you can set a breakpoint so your program stops at a certain point. You can then examine the stack using various commands.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html

Answer (score 1):

A tool for 'visual' debugging: Eclipse CDT
When you run debug in Eclipse CDT, you can see almost everything nicely sorted in tables, without struggling navigating through horrific GDB commands (yet it's back-end is GDB).
Tough, it's still a bit tricky to use this debugger. But Youtube and Google will provide you with sufficient tutorials.